# Powershell script to check if account is enabled from CSV file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of about 1000 usernames in a CSV file and I need to check if they are enabled or not.  I can't seem to find a tutorial on how to do this without using a third-party snapin, which isn't an option.

It seems like this should be a rather simple script, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
function Test-UserAccountDisabled
{
     param($account)
     $searcher = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
     $searcher.filter = "(sAMAccountName=$Account)"
     $user=$searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry()
     if($($user.userAccountControl) -band 0x2){$true}else{$false}
}

$file = Select-FileDialog -Title "Select a file" -Directory "C:\" -Filter "All Files (*.*)|*.*"

$users = Import-Csv $file

foreach($account in $users)
{
  Test-UserAccountDisabled($account)
}
```

It returns with "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that you call functions the same as cmdlets in powershell, without parens. `Test-UserAccountDisabled $account` **not** `Test-UserAccountDisabled($account)`.  Parens are only for .NET methods.  This might be part of the problem.

Comment: In that case the result is the same, though, since there is only a single argument.

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: It seems to be happening on the $searcher.filter line. Is that the right way to add the $Account variable to the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's in $Account?

Assuming the CSV file contains a SamAccountName column:

```
Import-Csv $file | Foreach-Object{

    $user = ([ADSISEARCHER]"(samaccountname=$($_.SamAccountName))").FindOne()

    if($user)
    {
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
            IsDisabled = $user.GetDirectoryEntry().InvokeGet('AccountDisabled')
        }
    }
    else
    {
            Write-Warning "Can't find user '$($_.SamAccountName)'"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it returns "Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] doesn't contain a method named 'GetDirectoryEntry'.

Comment: I had a type, it is fixed now, give it another try.

Comment: Same error, I had already corrected the typo, but it's still the same error. There is another one in ADSISEARCHER.

Comment: Do you have a SamAccountName column in the CSV file? Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: I would try to debug the script in ISE and step through the code to fins where it is failing. Do you get the error for all users in the file?

Comment: Yes, it happens for all users in the file. It doesn't recognize $_.GetDirectoryEntry.....is there another way to call GetDirectoryEntry?

Comment: I just noticed that, man, this is my bad! Rreplace $_ with $user. I updated the code, please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As commenter `latkin` mentioned, it looks like you're calling `Test-UserAccountDisabled` like a C#-style function.  Parenthesis mean arrays or expressions in PowerShell.  Change

```
Test-UserAccountDisabled ($account)
```

to

```
Test-UserAccountDisabled $account
```

If that still doesn't solve the problem, please let us know **what line number the error is happening on**.

Comment: While technically correct this doesn't change anything here, because there is only a single argument.